# jQuery Popup not displaying string with square brackets inside

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have been stuck on this for awhile. I am not too sure where the problem is as it does not throw any errors. This code works for most strings. However, I noticed that the jQuery Popup function does not run whenever there is a special character in the string I want it to show. In this case it seems to not popup due to "[" and "]" in my string. I tried replacing "[" and "]" with "(" and ")" but it still doesn't seem to work as intended.

Here is my example code:

```
string test = tbICD91.Text; //<--"J43.0"
string codeDescription = string.Empty;
codeDescription = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim(); //<--"Unilateral pulmonary emphysema [MacLeod's syndrome]"
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(codeDescription))
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('Cannot find description to code in textbox');", true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "ScrollPage", "ResetScrollPosition();", true);
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", string.Format("ShowPopup('{0}: {1} ');", test, codeDescription), true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "ScrollPage", "ResetScrollPosition();", true);
}
return;
```

Here is my jQuery Popup Function on front-end with div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup(message) {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").html(message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "ICD Code Description",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });
    };
</script>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none"></div>
```

I've been trying all sorts of escape strings or and literal strings like `@"Unilateral pulmonary emphysema [MacLeod's syndrome]"` and replacing the square brackets with something else but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if its because of jQuery or C# that its not working because it's not throwing any error. It just seems to skip the popup whenever a square bracket appears in the string. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the square brackets, the problem is the single quote `'` in `MacLeod's Syndrome` which is terminating the argument to `ShowPopup` early. Escape that quote to fix the issue.

```
codeDescription = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim().Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I didn't see that one. Thanks for helping me on this simple problem....well this is awkward...